# load based processing of data

Tags: lucene, monitoring

I am setting up a apache lucene based search engine service but I wanted all the indexing and page rank processing to happen afterwards when there's less load on the server as it would be running other services too. By that time I would be storing the data to be indexed temporarily. So basically I had to somehow figure out when is the load below a certain level? Is there any way I could do that??

Comment: Are you asking if how to track queries per second? (Or per minute etc.)

Comment: yeah...like my server would be handling websites or data storage or maybe both...point is I wanted to use my servers resources in the most efficient manner...so is it even a good idea to do that? because the ways i know would be requiring significant server resources too...